# Get specific xml value in python

Tags: python, xml

i have the following xml file, coming from a url

```
<queue name="triggerPO.EPOEPOImportEBDToPO-Start">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="10" enqueueCount="21" dequeueCount="21"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/triggerPO.EPOEPOImportEBDToPO-Start?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/triggerPO.EPOEPOImportEBDToPO-Start?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
<queue name="hibernateSearchQueue">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="1" enqueueCount="41648" dequeueCount="41648"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/hibernateSearchQueue?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/hibernateSearchQueue?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
<queue name="POEPOExportSearchRequestToEPO-XML-IPX">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="10" enqueueCount="0" dequeueCount="0"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/POEPOExportSearchRequestToEPO-XML-IPX?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/POEPOExportSearchRequestToEPO-XML-IPX?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
```

How can i get the "**stats size value**" (e.g. the "0") of the "hibernateSearchQueue" attribute only. This should be implemented in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html):

```
from lxml import etree
```

You XML sample is not well-formed, so I add the `<root>` element:

```
content = """\
<root>
<queue name="triggerPO.EPOEPOImportEBDToPO-Start">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="10" enqueueCount="21" dequeueCount="21"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/triggerPO.EPOEPOImportEBDToPO-Start?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/triggerPO.EPOEPOImportEBDToPO-Start?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
<queue name="hibernateSearchQueue">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="1" enqueueCount="41648" dequeueCount="41648"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/hibernateSearchQueue?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/hibernateSearchQueue?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
<queue name="POEPOExportSearchRequestToEPO-XML-IPX">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="10" enqueueCount="0" dequeueCount="0"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/POEPOExportSearchRequestToEPO-XML-IPX?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/POEPOExportSearchRequestToEPO-XML-IPX?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
</root>
"""
```

To parse a XML file, you can use `etree.parse()`, but, here, I use `etree.XML()` to parse the string.

```
tree = etree.XML(content)
```

To get the "hibernateSearchQueue" queue, you can use an XPath expression:

```
queues = tree.xpath("//queue[@name = 'hibernateSearchQueue']")
queue = queues[0]
etree.dump(queue)
```

You'll get:

```
<queue name="hibernateSearchQueue">
  <stats size="0" consumerCount="1" enqueueCount="41648" dequeueCount="41648"/>
  <feed>
    <atom>
      queueBrowse/hibernateSearchQueue?view=rss&amp;feedType=atom_1.0
    </atom>
    <rss>
      queueBrowse/hibernateSearchQueue?view=rss&amp;feedType=rss_2.0
    </rss>
  </feed>
</queue>
```

To get the stats size value, you can do this:

```
for stats in queue.iter("stats"):
    print(stats.attrib["size"])
# 0
```